# Cumsum based on condition of the column, Changing condition starting again cumsum

Tags: r, reset, cumsum

I have this Dataset and i want to find the cumsum of difftime based on Status and the desired out put is the " outputcumsum"

```
x                     Status   difftime            outputcumsum
24/11/2020 15:59:22     A        0                        0
24/11/2020 16:29:22     A        0.5                      0.5
25/11/2020 08:02:36     B        15,5538888888889         15,5538888888889          
26/11/2020 08:45:30     B        24,715                   40,2688888889
26/11/2020 09:15:59     A        0,508055555555556        0,508055555555556
26/11/2020 09:45:59     A        0,5                      1,00805555556
```

I tried this but it didn't help

```
Data%>%
group_by(Status)%>%
summarise(outputcumsum=cumsum(difftime))
```

it gives me this instead of what i want

```
    x                     Status   difftime            outputcumsum
    24/11/2020 15:59:22     A        0                        0
    24/11/2020 16:29:22     A        0.5                      0.5
    25/11/2020 08:02:36     B        15,5538888888889         15,5538888888889          
    26/11/2020 08:45:30     B        24,715                   40,2688888889
    26/11/2020 09:15:59     A        0,508055555555556        1,00805555556
    26/11/2020 09:45:59     A        0,5                      1,50805555556
```

Do you may know any solution?

Comment: This gives me again the second output I want it to reset cumsum at the A after B, instead of this it continues cumsum from the firsts As

Answer (score 1):

you can use base R's `rle()` as follows

```
Data$outputcumsum <- ave(Data$difftime, with(rle(Data$Status), rep(1:length(values), lengths)) , FUN = cumsum)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `rleid` from `data.table` in `group_by` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

Data%>%
  group_by(grp = rleid(Status)) %>%
  mutate(outputcumsum = cumsum(difftime))
```

Or do everything in `data.table` itself.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(Data)[, outputcumsum := cumsum(difftime), rleid(Status)]
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
Data %>%
    group_by(grp = with(rle(Status), rep(seq_along(values), lengths))) %>%
    mutate(outputcumsum = cumsum(difftime))
```